# Html - rendering a text containing html tags displays the tags as plain text

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using angularJS, where I have a property 'description', which I have to display to the user. The problem is that this property contains some html code, which is being displayed to the user as plain text. Here is my code:

```
<span class="cst-bold">Activity description </span>
{{pack.activities.current['description']}}
```

I also tried to surround the variable with

, but it also did not solve anything. Just a little different formatting. Here is the result after using the `<pre>` tag:

[image]

How can I solve the problem with tags? Thank you!

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#strict-contextual-escaping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a custom filter trusted and `ng-bind-html` Example

```js
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('Ctrl',function($scope){
     $scope.description="<h1>Hallo World!</h1>";
})
.filter('trusted', function($sce){
    return function(html){return $sce.trustAsHtml(html)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
   <span class="cst-bold">Activity description </span>
   <span>{{description}}</span>
   <span ng-bind-html="description|trusted"></span>
</div>
```